# Evaluating integral with branch of log

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, complex-numbers

I'm having trouble understanding what this question even means really.

"Let $\gamma$ be the semi-circle from $2i$ to $-2i$ that passes through $2$ in the positive direction. Find $\int_\gamma z^{-1}dz$ by using a suitable *branch of $\log$ as an anti-derivative*."

When I look at my book there seems to be some hand-waving with an example simply using the definition $$z^a=\exp(a\mathrm{log}(z))$$ but then more or less doing the integral parametrically.

Would just like some clarification as to how to do this problem really. I can't remember seeing an integral done with a branch before.

Thanks.

Comment: Just choose a branch of $\log$ that is defined in a neighbourhood of the semicircle. All branches differ by a constant (integer multiple of $2\pi i$) on the semicircle, so it doesn't matter which you choose. Typically, the principal branch is the most familiar and hence used.

Comment: So, $\log(z)=\mathrm{Log}(z)+2n\pi i=\ln|z|+i\arg(z)$ and since we're on the semicircle, $\ln|z|=\ln(2)$ and since we choose the principal branch we should choose $n=0 \Leftrightarrow \arg(z)=0$? But even then, I don't see how I would use that to evaluate the integral...

Comment: What is to stop me from simply going $\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z} =\left.\log(z)\right|_{2i}^{-2i}=\log(-2i)-\log(2i)=i\pi$? Is the "suitable branch" part of the question sort of superfluous? (This is the correct answer btw.)

Comment: You have the bounds the wrong way round, it's $\log z\bigl\lvert_{-2i}^{2i} = \log (2i) - \log (-2i) = \pi i$. Nothing is to stop you, that is how it's intended to be solved. "Suitable branch" just means you have to choose a branch whose domain contains the path of integration (and say which branch you use). It's not superfluous, but it's not something deep.